# Securing Back end services in Azure API Management using OAuth2 Client Credentials flow

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, openid-connect, azure-api-management

I have deployed a .NET Core Web API and provided access through Azure API Management. I now wish to secure the back end using OAuth2 Client Credentials flow.

I have added Azure AD Authentication as follows:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADBearer(options =>
                {
                    Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                });
```

I have created an App Registration and Client Secret in Azure AD and confirmed it is working by creating a token using the code below and calling the API.

```
var clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

            var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);

            return result.AccessToken;
```

Is it possible to use this flow in Azure API Management? I would like Azure API Management to handle acquiring the token and passing in the header.

The closest I have found is the following article but this seems to involve the consumer of the API passing headers which seems to defeat the point of the API Management subscription functionality

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad

Comment: Refer to https://tbfconsulting.com.au/securing-an-azure-apim-using-oauth-2-0-client-credential-grant/

Comment: Thanks for the link. In this scenario it looks like the client has to authenticate which is similar to the Microsoft example.

I am still confused about 2 things: 
1) What is the point of the API Management subscription key if the client is authenticating anyway
2) What stops the client going directly to the back end service. 

I would've thought there needed to be a way of ensuring that the back end API could only be called from API Management. 

I can't see a way of doing this other than using certificates or VNET (which is a premium feature)

Comment: As per my understanding, what you are trying is not secured. Actually Client should handle the token part and pass to the Azure APIM.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the only way to do that at APIM side is to use send-request policy to do OAuth flow. That will require you to give APIM client id and secret, but you could use named values to store those securely.